# Why do I need to execute explicitly Groovy trampoline.call() method for recursion?

Tags: recursion, groovy

I am running with Groovy 'recursively' into a Map and trying to change all values which are BigDecimal typed to Double using Tail-recursion to avoid StackOverFlow.

I already did it creating a method using annotation @TailRecursive. Now I am trying with a simple closure and trampoline, like this:

```
def mapToTest = [
    key1: "String1",
    key2: new BigDecimal(2),
    key3: "String3",
    key4: [attr1:'attrValue1', attr2: new BigDecimal(4)],
    key5:new BigDecimal(5)
]

def deepDoubler 
deepDoubler = { Map map, boolean rec ->
   println "is rec? ${rec}" 
   map.each { k, v ->
       println (v instanceof Map)
       if (v instanceof Map){
           println "calling recursively... ${v}"
           deepDoubler.trampoline(v, true)
       } else if (v instanceof BigDecimal) {
           map[k] = new Double(0)
       }
    }
}.trampoline()
deepDoubler(mapToTest, false)
```

I added boolean parameter just to print and indeed I am able to print 'calling recursively' but the method is never executed unless I add the method call() after trampoline instruction.

```
if (v instanceof Map){
 println "calling recursively... ${v}"
 deepDoubler.trampoline(v, true).call() // call() here otherwise it doesn't run
```

Does anyone knows why it works just when I execute call() method? I tried many API examples and they work well without explicit call(), but I didn't find any example with Map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trampoline` method does not invoke the closure but decorates it and returns the modified closure - see [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#trampoline(java.lang.Object)). You need to call decorated closure explicitly via `()` or `call()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Taking the example [link](https://wakeupcode.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/groovy-functional-sugar-trampoline/) why here there is not explicit call()?

Comment: It is, in this line: `assert sizeList(1..10000) == 10000`, exactly here `(1..10000)` :)

Comment: @CassioDC, if my answer solves the problem please accept it.